# Retrieve the result of an OR logic operation in JS

Tags: javascript, boolean, logical-operators, boolean-logic

A logical statement always returns a boolean value, true or false.
But how do you retrieve the true statement in a OR logical operation?

Comment: It does not always return a boolean value in JS. If you want a boolean, convert it using the logical NOT operator `var x = !!(foo || bar)`

Comment: true statement? do you mean expression? Are you talking about the coalesce operator?

Comment: The question as phrased makes no sense at all so any answer is acceptable and a correct response.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the OR and AND operators always return one of their operands. The OR operator returns the first falsy operand (and doesn't evaluate any operands after that) or the last operand if they are all truthy. The AND operator similarly returns the first truthy operand or the last operand if they are all falsy.

If you wish the result to be a boolean, you can use the `!` operator which returns `true` for falsy values and `false` for truthy values.

To sum it up:

`!!(a || b)` will return `true` if `a` and/or `b` are truthy and `false` otherwise.

`a || b` will return `a` if `a` is truthy and `b` otherwise.

**EDIT:**
After some explanations it seems that what you are looking for is separating the evaluation of the OR.

```
if (a === 56) {
    // a is what you are looking for
} else if (b === 56) {
    // b is what you are looking for
} else {
    // neither a nor b are what you are looking for
}
```

The above piece of code does the exact same evaluations as your code but you have a branch of code that executes when the first expression is true and another branch which executes if the first expression is false and the second expression is true.

Comment: But how do you retrieve which one is true in a function, e.g. `var a = 45, b = 56; function something (a === 56 || b === 56){ var result = ; // return/retrieve operation true value (which is b)}`

Comment: Could you clarify what the argument(s) of the function is? Please separate the function definition and the actuall example call.

Comment: Sorry it is an if statement in which I want to retrieve the result. `var a = 45, b = 56; if (a === 56 || b === 56){ var result = ; // return/retrieve operation true value (which is b)}`

Comment: "Returns the first falsy operand" . . .? Sure.